# How to Handle Clob Data Type in Excel from SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle

I need to retrieve data from an Oracle view that has a column defined as a clob Data Type due to the possibility of there being more than 4000 characters in the field.

I have a subroutine in Excel VBA that executes a query and puts the results into a cell range.

I encounter error

> "Data Type Not Supported"

at

```
strSQL = "Select clob_field from Table1"
```

Is it even possible to query for a Column of Clob Data Type in Excel?

I cant find any information which will indicate where I am going wrong.

```vb
Sub Get_Data4()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strUsername As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strInput As String

'strUsername = InputBox("Input User Name")

'strPassword = InputBox("Input Password")

strCon = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "Select clob_field from Table1"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Open strSQL
Sheet1.Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
cn.Close

Call Get_Data
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you get?

Comment: Sorry copied wrong text it says data type not supported.

Comment: Where does it say it? On what line?

Comment: strSQL = "Select clob_field from Table1" basically here. I have a field  that contains 4000 char plus which can be stored in oracle fine as a clob. I'm not sure how to query oracle to bring the clob field into excel by using VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue. I was getting "Unspecified error" while trying to open the recordset. I found that using Oracle Home driver resolves this issue.

Please follow the below steps to configure Oracle Home Driver in your machine -

1. Install Oracle Instant Client 12C
2. Find this path - `C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client\Network\Admin\Sample`
3. Copy both "sqlnet.ora" and "tnsnames.ora" files
4. Paste in Admin folder (as mentioned in above path)
5. Edit "tnsnames.ora" file
6. Add the below code at the end

   ```
   [DS Name as you wish] =
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [your DB server name or IP])(PORT = [Port Number]))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = [Your DB Service Name]")
       )
     )
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Check the driver name in ODBC Drivers (`Control Panel -> Administrative Panel 
   -> Data Sources (ODBC)`)
   My driver name is shown as - Oracle in OraClient12Home1
9. Try the below connection string

   ```
   ConnectionString="Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};DBQ=Your SERVICE_NAME;User ld=User ID;pwd=Password;"
   ```